# can SFML and glad be used in the same project

Tags: c++, sfml, glad

I am compleatly new to both SFML and OpenGL. Following the holy LearnOpenGl tutorial I managed to make a triangle, but now I have used SFML for a lot of a project already and I need to do something in 3d, thus (I think) I need glfw and glad but when I try to glad gives me the following error: `OpenGL header already included, remove this include, glad already provides it`. If I have made a big mistake I dont understand why so could someone please explain how to use them both or why only one can be used?

Comment: What includes do you have before glad?

Comment: just sfml/OpenGL.hpp

Comment: You have to choose between SFML and GLFW (both can be used with OpenGL). If you choose the former, it seems you don't need glad. If you choose the latter, you do need it (or a similar library).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand glad already includes the necessary GL headers. So just do what the error message tells you and remove your own "include" of OpenGL. Only include the glad headers.

Also from my experience you do NOT need GLFW when using SMFL, as SFML provides a valid OpenGL context for you when creating a window.

Answer (score 0):

**That error can generally be avoided simply by moving the GLAD include above any SFML or GLFW includes.**

Also, SFML and GLFW provide similar functionalities, so you should really choose one or the other for a project, but not both.

If you include either of their headers first, they will attempt to load OpenGL headers.  GLAD is providing an alternative to the standard OpenGL headers, but if the OpenGL headers have already been included, it can't do its magic properly.